# javascript marquee with import text file external

Tags: javascript, html

i've a file 1 mb of txt, i want import in my page html, and assign a varible, then use function scroll text in javascript with text in variable globally but scroll "undefinited" why ?

my code in header

```
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain attribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

my code in body

```
<script>
 w3-include-html="listone.html"
</script>
 
<script>
var $f=includeHTML() ;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xbMarquee.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  function init() { rtl_marquee.start(); }
  var $f=includeHTML() ;
  var rtl_marquee_Text = $f ;
  var rtl _marquee_Direction = 'left';
  var `rtl_marquee_Contents='<span style="font-family:Comic Sans MS;font-size: 12pt; white-space:   nowrap;">' + $f + '</span>';
  rtl_marquee = new xbMarquee('rtl_marquee', '29px', '90%', 6, 100, rtl_marquee_Direction, 'scroll', rtl_marquee_Contents);
  window.setTimeout( init, 200);
-->
</script>
```

Comment: Why is `<div w3-include-html="listone.html"></div>` enclosed within a `<script>`? That's not JavaScript, it's HTML.

Comment: You have many syntax errors. `var rtl_ marquee_Text = $f  ;` should be `var rtl_marquee_Text = $f ;` and `var rtl _marquee_Direction = 'left';` should be `var rtl_marquee_Direction = 'left';` and your last line is also incorrect. You must make your code syntactically correct before trying to run it.